# what about the order of global vs local include files in c++

Tags: c++, include

Is there a recommended practice that for example global includes shall go befor local includes. By global I mean `#include <iostream>` and local `#include "myhdr.h"`. Is it some prefered order and why?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, there are recommendations. Some of them are:

- **Order**: If you're in MyClass.cpp, put "MyClass.h" first, then C-headers, then STL headers, then your project's headers.
- **Internal order**: In each of these categories, use alphabetical order.
- **Syntax**: Use `#inlcude <>` for C and STL and `#include ""` for your own headers.

They should look something like this:

```
#include "MyClass.h"

#include <time.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#include "MyFolder/MyAwesomeClass.h"
#include "MyOtherFolder/MyOtherClass.h"
```

For more recommendations on good coding style you can take a look at [Google's C++ Style Guide](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.xml). They give a good explanation on *why* you should do this in [this section](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.xml#Names_and_Order_of_Includes).

Comment: This answer is a bit incomplete as it doesn't answer the "why" part of the question.

Comment: @ereOn I added a link to Google's explanation :)

Comment: Beware about Google's Style Guide. It is good for Google, in their own very specific environment which is a mix of C and C++. In pure C++ codebases, there are parts (no exception, no streams, two-phase init) that are counterproductive.

Comment: @MatthieuM. I don't do all they say either, but I do agree with their readability argument about streams (which doesn't keep me from using them anyway)

Comment: @alestanis: Yes, readability and internationalization are a concern. On the other hand, the ability to dump full objects for logging is invaluable, and `printf` does not handle this (at all) as it involves overloading. A C++ version of `printf`, using variadic templates, could solve the issue :)